# Auto Encoder didn't improve my neural network loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, data-cleaning

so I'm trying to improve my neural network result by using auto encoder for preprocessing. The data looks more or less like this :

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -70 | -76 | -76 | -80 | 1 |
| -93 | -100 | -94 | -100 | 4 |
| -88 | -83 | -89 | -85 | 2 |
| -100 | -95 | -91 | -99 | 4 |
| -100 | -86 | -82 | -80 | 3 |

-100 is actually the default value for null because the device can't get the data.

I used tensorflow for the neural network model, and also using parametric tuning for searching the best results. Before I used auto encoder, the loss is around 1 to 2. But after using the auto encoder, the loss become 3. My target is to reduce losses so that it become less than 1. I use simple auto encoder input_size -> input_size/2 -> input_size/2 -> input_size for the layer without using the Target column.

What I do is just training the auto encoder using all raw data, then save the auto encoder model. After that, I predict the raw data to model A, then the data that has been processed by model A is used to train the neural network (parametric tuning) to predict the Target.

This is the raw data graphic :

[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBfYS.png)

and this is after the data is processed by the auto encoder :

[processed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTpug.png)

Is there something wrong with my step? Or is there any other way to improve my model loss? And I can only use neural networks because it's my assignment

I have tried to use simple auto encoder, and the graphic after the data is processed looks like it is good. But when I use the processed data to train the neural network for predicting the answer, the losses are worse than before using auto encoder. I'm looking to improve the loss so it become less than 1.

This is the code for hyperparametric tuning that I used :

```
def build_model(hp):
model = keras.Sequential()
#model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], )))
# Tune the number of layers.
for i in range(hp.Int("num_layers", 1, 5)):
    model.add(
        layers.Dense(
            # Tune number of units separately.
            units=hp.Int(f"units_{i}", min_value=2, max_value=10, step=1),
            activation=hp.Choice("activation", ["relu"]),
        )
    )
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="relu"))
learning_rate = hp.Float("lr", min_value=1e-4, max_value=3e-1, sampling="log")
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate),
    loss="mean_squared_error",
    metrics=["mae"],
)
return model
```

build_model(keras_tuner.HyperParameters())

```
tuner = keras_tuner.BayesianOptimization(
hypermodel=build_model,
objective="val_loss",
max_trials=40,
overwrite=True,
directory="my_dir",
project_name="helloworld",
```

)

```
tuner.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, validation_data=(x_test, y_test),callbacks=[keras.callbacks.TensorBoard("/tmp/tb_logs")])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your description of your implementation it doesn't seem to me that there are any major problems in your training pipeline, however in my opinion there are aspects that can be improved:

1. **The architecture of the model**: absolutely you should add more layers to your architecture. You can also implement a convolutional autoencoder, that is, one that introduces 1D convolutional layers. These architectural changes I am quite convinced will bring improvements.
2. **Training hyperparams**: you didn't report much information about training parameters, however I think these can influence training. Reduce the learning rate and introduce an early stopping condition with a patience value equal to 10/15.